# R quirk: evaluation phase of substitute

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand R's non standard evaluation. Here's a sample quirk:

```
> f<-function(x) substitute(x)
> g<-function(x) deparse(f(x))
> h<-function(x) deparse(substitute(x))

> g(1:10)
[1] "x"
> h(1:10)
[1] "1:10"
```

How come? What is the exact source of difference between g and h results?

---

Edit: `deparse` is immaterial. It is easier to demonstrate with:

```
> f<-function(a) substitute(a)
> g<-function(x) f(x)

> f(1:10)
1:10
> g(1:10)
x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be easier to see if you change f:

```
f<-function(a) substitute(a)
g<-function(x) deparse(f(x))
h<-function(x) deparse(substitute(x))
```

In `g(1:10)`, `1:10` is passed to `f` as `x`,  and `substitute` returns `x`, the parse tree (note it doesn't return `a`). Deparse in `g` then turns the unevaluated `x` into `"x"`

In `h`, `1:10` isn't falling through to another function to get to `substitute`. The unevaluated expression is now `1:10`, not `x`.   Deparse in `h` then turns the unevaluated `1:10` into `"1:10"`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not grokking it. What do you mean by 'passed to `f` as `x`'?  What is the full order of operations/views?

Comment: Working from your edit.  In your call to  `f`,   `a` is your formal, and in the calling environment of `substitute` `a` is the expression `1:10`, so that unevaluated expression is returned. In your call to `g`,  within the calling environment of `substitute`, `a` is the expression `x` (`1:10` having been passed as `x` by `g`). So an unevaluated `x` is returned.

Comment: `substitute` is smart enough to not just return the formal name. That would make it pretty useless.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm accepting the answer - just adding my own phrasing as a separate one.

Answer (score 0):

It helps me to rewrite this example -

```
> f<-function(a) substitute(a)
> g<-function(x) f(x)

> f(1:10)
1:10
> g(1:10)
x
```

in the following way:

```
> f<-function(a) substitute(a)
> g<-function(x) f(a=x)

> f(a=1:10)
1:10
> g(x=1:10)
x
```

Now it seems natural that in both cases the 'unevaluated' argument is the blank at `f(a=_)`. This is apparently what `substitute` sees and uses.